# error passing data to tableController

Tags: uiviewcontroller, swift2, xcode7

I am new to swift, and I am trying to make a lobby screen with a text field and a button to move on to the next screen. I connected it in segue to "show" the next view controller.
I need it to check my input field and only continue if the field is not empty, and of course to pass the name to the next view controller, also I cannot manage to show and hide my keyboard (stays on when segueing to the second view controller). Does anyone know how to make a button check the field and only then move to the next view controller?
here is my code(mostly auto generated):

```
import UIKit

    class LobbyController: UIViewController {

        @IBOutlet weak var playerNameField: UITextField!


        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            playerNameField.becomeFirstResponder()
        }

        override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
            super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
            // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
        }

        @IBAction func nameLabel(sender: UITextField) {
            playerNameField.becomeFirstResponder()
        }

        @IBAction func startGameButton(sender: AnyObject) {
            self.playerNameField.resignFirstResponder()

            }
    }
```

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do some input validation before segueing, you should not connect the segue directly to the button, but segue from code.

First you should control click on your button and remove the segue action created.

Now you should create the segue from the view controller, by control dragging from the yellow view controller icon in the document outline.

[image]

Then, click on the segue in the storyboard and open its attributes inspector and add a segue identifier.

[image]

Now you can perform this segue in code.

So for the IBAction of your button press you can say something like:

```
@IBAction func startGameButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        if self.playerNameField.text?.characters.count != 0{
            self.playerNameField.resignFirstResponder()
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("MySegueId", sender: self.playerNameField.text!)
        }

}
```